# Using qgis-stubs in pycharm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pycharm

I downloaded and installed qgis-stubs 0.2.0 in QGIS 3.22.3.

For development I am using pycharm.

How do I use qgis-stubs module in pycharm?

Comment: Have you seen the blog post from 2014 ( https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/pycharm/ )? Did you try any of that and if yes where did you fail?